# Trigger mouseover on object below pointer

Tags: jquery

I currently have a lot of elements with tooltips on, triggered by mouseover.

At some point, im redrawing my whole page, including the divs with the tooltip. Now if the user does not touch the mouse and the div stays in the same place, the tooltip (if active) disappears.

Currently I can make the tooltip appear with `$("<div>").trigger("mouseover")`, but the problem is, I dont know which object is under the mousecursor, so I trigger every tooltip on the page, and not just the one where the mouse it.

Edit:
I was going for something along the line of:

```
div.mousemove(function(evt) { target = evt.target })
```

And on redraw:

```
target.trigger("mouseover")
```

to trigger the tooltip again. But it says "Uncaught TypeError: target.trigger is not a function". (target is the div)

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: What do you mean with "But does not work"? It sounds to me like you'll need a solution close to the one you already tried.

Comment: I tried elaborating a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
$("div:hover").trigger("mouseover")
```

Comment: Thx man :D Didnt know you could do all the css stuff in the selector :)

Comment: Damn, that's pretty clever. Here I was writing up an answer where I save some data to a variable to use later, but this is much more practical and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

`target` is your case is most likely an instance of `HTMLDivElement`, not a `jQuery` object. Simply wrap your object as a jQuery object before calling `$.fn.trigger` on it.

```
$(target).trigger('mouseover');
```